# Laravel RabbitMQ with dynamic routing key

Tags: laravel, rabbitmq

I'm using https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq library for rabbitMQ connection with Laravel.

Is there any way to dynamically set 'exchange_routing_key' when generating Job record?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use this approach:

```
(new YourJobClass)->onQueue('your_routing_key');
```